# linux mint app installation

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, dpkg, atom-editor

I can't install anything on my mint linux and this is this is the terminals answer

```
dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23+linuxmint6) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate which version if Linux Mint you are using; it is not obvious from your question. Please also post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` so we can understand how you configured the package manager.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to provide the command - or the process - which led you to this point (are you running `dpkg` directly?)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some missing dependencies preventing dpkg to fulfill your request. I recommend running the command `sudo apt-get -f install` and checking what it proposes in order to solve the issue. If you are OK with the proposed changes, press Y and let it run.